# wp-admin page only outputs partial html

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I tried migrating a blog over from apache on one server to nginx on another.

front page and articles are all fine (using permalinks). wp-login.php is fine. But /wp-admin only outputs partial html, stops somewhere in the  section after a

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

        root /home/someblog/www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        #this isn't really example.com ;)
        server_name example.com;

location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        # I tried commenting this as well
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

       # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was because php5-curl wasn't installed... apt-get install php5-curl fixed it ;)